# MSSQL Finding Total of a column and carry other data with it

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by, sum

I have the following table to work with, which I can not change. I have to work with what I have.

```
 Id (int auto int)
 CustomerName (varchar)
 CustomerNumber (int)
 Date (date)
 WeeklyAmount (int)
```

What I would like to do is grab all the data per customer and add all the weekly amounts for a specific year. Eventually I will want to compare two years together, but right now I am working on the data to sum up the weekly totals per CustomerNumber.

I am using:

```
 Select
 CustomerNumber, SUM (WeeklyAmount) as Total from  
 Customers.RECORDS GROUP BY CustomerNumber;
```

This works fine, however, I want to return the CustomerName as well. Eventually I will have to place in the SQL for getting specific years and compare them. However, I have to tackle this part first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a 1-to-1 relationship between `CustomerName` and `CustomerNumber`:

```
Select
CustomerNumber, CustomerName, SUM (WeeklyAmount) as Total from  
Customers.RECORDS GROUP BY CustomerNumber, CustomerName;
```

If the relationship is not 1-to-1, then I suppose you'd need to define what exactly represents a customer in the phrase `grab all the data per customer`.